# Tail-Recursion to get a Map of word counts

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, scala

I want to read a file and store the number of occurrences of each word in a Map, using tail recursion. I came up with the following; it seems to work; does it look like it's right?

```
def countWordsinFile(reader:java.util.Scanner, wordCounts:Map[String,Int]): Map[String,Int] = {
    if (!reader.hasNext()) wordCounts
    else {
        val word = reader.next()
        countWordsinFile(reader, wordCounts + (word -> {wordCounts.getOrElse(word,0)+1}))
    }
}
// the function is called with a reader from a .txt file and wordCounts is an empty Map()
```

Is this tail-recursive? If not, then how can I make it so?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is tail-recursive. Just annotate countWordsInFile with `@tailrec` and the compiler will check that for you.
Btw: why not name the method `countWords`? The Scanner is not limited to read from files.

Comment: I didn't consider that, thank you for the tip/review.

Answer (score 2):

> it seems to work; does it look like it's right?

It works, and it looks "OK", but it could be better:

- When a method call doesn't mutate the state, it's customary to omit the parentheses. I'm talking about the `reader.hasNext()`, the recommended way is to write as `reader.hasNext`
- Users of this function should not have to know to pass in an empty `Map`. It would be more ergonomic to declare the map parameter with a default value of `Map.empty`
- Instead of using the `+` operator to append to the map, a slightly more compact and more idiomatic way is to use the `map.updated(key, value)` method
- Since the "reader" is a `Scanner`, I'd call it "scanner" instead

Something like this:

```
object WordCounts extends App {

  println(countWordsinFile(new Scanner(new File("/tmp/words"))))

  @tailrec
  def countWordsinFile(scanner: Scanner, wordCounts: Map[String, Int] = Map.empty): Map[String, Int] = {
    if (!scanner.hasNext) wordCounts
    else {
      val word = scanner.next()
      countWordsinFile(scanner, wordCounts.updated(word, wordCounts.getOrElse(word, 0) + 1))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to count the number of words occurrences.

```
def numberOfWordOccurrences(words: Traversable[String]): Map[String, Int] = words.foldLeft(Map[String, Int]()) {
    case (occurrences, word) if (occurrences.get(word) == None) => occurrences + (word -> 1)
    case (occurrences, word) => occurrences + (word -> (occurrences(word) + 1))
}
```

Notes:

It is not tail-recursive. It is based on the `foldLeft` function of scala collections. I am not familiar with `java.util.Scanner` so you would have to look how you can get the input as a scala collection type. Also there are two scala types:

- `scala.util.parsing.combinator.lexical.Scanners` and
- `scala.util.parsing.combinator.lexical.Scanner`

I am not familiar with them, too, but maybe they do something similar like the Java class in a more Scala-ish way.